# Creating a .bar from .apk for Playbook using existing .p12 file

Tags: android, blackberry, apk, blackberry-playbook, pkcs#12

Long story short a previous employee created our last version of the Android for Playbook .bar file. When he left, he left me the .p12 file and the password but not the barsigner.csk and barsigner.db as mentioned here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Backup-and-Restore-BlackBerry-Code-Signing-Keys/ta-p/837925. Is it possible to update the .bar file with just the .p12 file and password, and not have to request new signing keys from RIM?

Comment: I know this doesn't help you now, but under no circumstances can your company's code signing files be left under the control of one person.  There's no way that one guy leaving (or even getting hit by a bus one morning and never returning to work) should disrupt your business like this.  Please, please, please keep important files somewhere where more than one person has access to them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the answer is no. To complicate maters, you will not be able to update an existing application in AppWorld with a new key. You should take this problem to RIM developer support to determine the best course of action.